# C++11 Observers Pass parameters on Notify

Tags: c++11, notify, observers

I'm coming from C# and trying to implement a simple Events/EventHandler pattern in c++11 which i believe the common name is Observers and signals, i know there are boost library and others but i dont want to use any external libs.

While searching online I found a simple implementation for what I need, so I took and modified the code and it works ok.

My problem is that the parameters are passed when registering events/observers, and not when raising/signaling/notifying which I find a bit awkward.

```
class EventManager
{
private:

static std::map<EventType, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> _eventHandlers;

public:
EventManager() = default;


template <typename EventHandler>
static void RegisterEventHandler(EventType&& eventType, EventHandler&& eventHandler)
{
    EventManager::_eventHandlers[std::move(eventType)].push_back(std::forward<EventHandler>(eventHandler));
}   

static void Raise(const EventType& event)
{
    for (const auto& eventHandler : EventManager::_eventHandlers.at(event))
    {

        eventHandler();
    }
}

// disallow copying and assigning
EventManager(const EventManager&) = delete;
EventManager& operator=(const EventManager&) = delete;


};
```

Can anyone help me to extend the following code by adding the functionality to accept parameters when raising the event as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this solves your question:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -o /tmp/events /tmp/events.cpp && /tmp/events
// handler=1 arg=1
// handler=2 arg=1
// handler=1 arg=2
// handler=2 arg=2

#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template<class EventType, class... HandlerArgs>
class EventManager
{
public:
    using EventHandler = std::function< void(HandlerArgs...) >;

    void register_event(EventType&& event, EventHandler&& handler)
        {
            _handlers[std::move(event)].push_back(std::forward<EventHandler>(handler));
        }

    void raise_event(const EventType& event, HandlerArgs&&... args)
        {
            for (const auto& handler: EventManager::_handlers.at(event)) {
                handler(std::forward<HandlerArgs>(args)...);
            }
        }

private:
    std::map<EventType, std::vector<EventHandler>> _handlers;

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    EventManager<int, int> m;
    m.register_event(1, [](int arg) { printf("handler=%d arg=%d\n", 1, arg); });
    m.register_event(1, [](int arg) { printf("handler=%d arg=%d\n", 2, arg); });
    m.raise_event(1, 1);
    m.raise_event(1, 2);
}
```

PS: I removed all the code regarding non-copiability and such, since it is not relevant to this question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this will not work if the methods are static since you need to initialize EventManager class and define arguments/parameters templates for eventhandlers, right?

Comment: Using static methods and a static `_handlers` member will work just fine.

Comment: ok thanks i will try to modify the code and get back to you if found any trouble if you dont mind, however, ill mark your answer as right one since you put the time and effort to help me out, appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since i havent got any answers on this, i figured a way to do so but i dont like it since i wanted a better way but well creating a static class that has static variables for each event, before raising the event , the caller will set those variables and the handler will read then reset them . this is dangerous approach especially with multi-threading since one or more threads might change the values while raising same event by mutli threads, so i had to implement some locking features to ensure thread safety.

Yes i know its not the best approach but as i'm not an expert in C++ and this question didnt get any comments nor answers, so this is the approach im following.